# Enabling php_error_log in Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I'm having an issue where Xampp isn't logging my errors. The file path doesn't exist when I search for it. I read some stuff about this that said I need to enable php_error_log from the php.ini file but i don't know what values to change.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a permissions issue (depending where you installed XAMPP). The XAMPP panel is sometimes unable to create the logs folder. Just create this directory:

```
    ...\xampp\php\logs
```

and the next time PHP error occurs it will create the php_error_log file inside and the logging will start.